# Jenkins assigning true to boolean variable and false to def variable

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Very simple and straightforward question:

Let's say we have this pipeline (I don't think there is a simpler example):

```
node {
    env.someEnvVariable = false

    boolean asBoolean = env.someEnvVariable ?: false
    def asDef         = env.someEnvVariable ?: false

    echo "asBoolean: $asBoolean"   // prints true because of Jenkins
    echo "asDef: $asDef"           // prints false
}
```

Why????

Defining a variable as `boolean` makes Jenkins assign it a true value but defining it as `def` assign it the real false value

Where is taking Jenkins that `true` value from?

edit: another example:

```
node {
    env.someEnvVariable = false
    boolean someBoolean = false
    def someVar = false

    echo "envVar: ${env.someEnvVariable}"     // prints false
    echo "someBoolean: ${someBoolean}"        // prints false
    echo "someVar: ${someVar}"                // prints false
    if (env.someEnvVariable != null) {
        someBoolean = env.someEnvVariable
        someVar = env.someEnvVariable
    }
    echo "envVar: ${env.someEnvVariable}"     // prints false
    echo "someBoolean: ${someBoolean}"        // prints true because of hack
    echo "someVar: ${someVar}"                // prints false
}
```

Answer (score 4):

My assumption is that when you assign environment variable it is interpreted as string `'false'`. That means in both cases you try to assign a string but assigning string to `boolean` variable is interpreted as true if it is not empty.

And ternary operator works the same way, you check if environment variable is true (not empty). It's not so it returns the variable itself.

Comment: This appears to be the case. I don't think this is the exact issue you're having, but there seems to be may similar issues in jenkins, this one concerning "boolean" parameters for example: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-46552

As a groovy newbie, it feels weird that you can write String someVar = false.

Comment: @sg_man I've just been traped like OP. That's why I hate languages with automagic type conversion...

Comment: Correct, all environment variables on any OS are always strings. If you want them to represent other data types, you have to parse the string

Answer (score 3):

This is due to "groovy truth": a non-empty string asserts as `true`.

https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/core-semantics.html#Groovy-Truth